# Magento 2: I just need to add custom font in email template

Tags: magento2

I just need to add Lucida Grande font in my email template. I have already added into _typography.less,_variables.less.

and its also showing in email-fonts.css. but it will not working in email template

is there any other way to apply this font in email.
please share if any idea.

I have use Luma theme, 
also _variables.less file,

```
@font-family-name__base: 'Open Sans';
@font-family-name__lucida: 'Lucida Grande';
@font-family-name__lato: 'Lato';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__lucida, @font-family-name__lato, @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;
```

in _typography.less file i edit

```
.lib-font-face(
        @family-name: @font-family-name__lucida,
        @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Lucida-Grande',
        @font-weight: 400,
        @font-style: normal
    );
```

Font family file path locate :

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/fonts/
```

Comment: you have to apply font location with full url like "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff"

Answer (score 1):

You normally have an `Magento_Email/email/header.html` in your theme that you are using.

Just add (in the `<head></head>` tag ):

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Different Lucida css styles :
https://www.cssfontstack.com/Lucida-Grande

This will apply to the whole body.

the `header.html` and the `footer.html` are pasted before and after every mail that you send so it comes in handy to use those to add general css styles instead of creating inline css styles.

**You can also add css files to it (in the header.html) for example :**

```
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Header"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var logo_height":"Email Logo Image Height",
"var logo_width":"Email Logo Image Width",
"var template_styles|raw":"Template CSS"
} @-->
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            {{var template_styles|raw}}
            {{css file="css/email.css"}}
        </style>
// and responsive 
        <style media="only screen and (max-width:600px)" type="text/css">
            table[class~="container"] {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        </style>
....
```

Then just add email.less to your `frontend/vendor/theme/web/css` folder and add css there.

In that less file you can add other less files or fonts with something like this

```
//  Font stylesheet @import is wrapped in a media query in order to prevent it from causing problems in Outlook
@media screen {
    @import 'source/_typography.less';
}
```

So its all a matter how you want to do it. You can import a compiled css within your html file and the less version of that you can import other less files and fonts like how you would normally.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go into the templates from the admin area: Marketing --> Email Templates

... and then you'll want to edit a template using inline CSS formatting.

HTML for email is a whole different animal. Due to security restrictions, you usually cannot load external stylesheets, so everything needs to be done in-line.

Here's a quick code example:

```
<p><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;"><strong>Thanks for your recentl order from our store.  We are thrilled to be shipping it out to you today.</strong></span></p>
```

Comment: i need to load this font for whole email body. so how can i do that

Comment: and i use Lucida Grande font, so we need to add this font in /fonts directory

Answer (score 0):

In:

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/web/css/source/_variables.less

Change:

```
@font-family-name__base: 'Lucida Grande';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base;
```

If you don't have this file in your theme, copy it from the parent theme (Magento_Blank).

This will most probably change the font in your entire Magento application and emails.

If you don't want to change the font for your shop or if the font isn't changed in the emails after your change, check this file:

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/web/css/source/_email-base.less

(again copy it from the parent theme if you don't have it in your theme)

Search for **"font-family"** and change all instances to 'Lucida Grande' or if you use the same font throughout your shop, change it to `@font-family__base`.

Also make sure the email template you are sending has the `header` template included. You can add it with `{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}` at the top of your email.

**EDIT**

You should stick to Magento's default way of implementing font & styles to emails, because different email clients have different ways of "reading" the styles. For example Gmail reads only the inline styles, while Outlook reads the non-inline styles.

So if you only use one way, many email clients won't receive the emails correctly.

Not to go into details, because email styling is a broad topic, Magento has the basics covered so if you're using `Magento Blank` as your parent theme, or the same "email style import logic" as Magento Blank, this is the way to go.

**EDIT 2**

If you are using Luma theme, and you are extending it. Just copy `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_email-base.less` to `/app/design/{vendor}/{theme}/web/css/source/_email-base.less`.

Luma isn't intended for extending, because it depends on Magento_Blank being the parent. And by extending it, you effectively removed the Blank theme as the parent and all of the stuff Luma depends on.

Comment: this all depends which theme you are using and what less files they use.

Comment: That is correct. But since he didn't specify details in the question, I based my answer on Magento defaults.

Comment: Thats why i explained how you integrate less filles in your own email template. Its compatible with default magento themes and also with themes where the parent is not Magento based

Comment: @Lez I have used Luma theme , and that have not _email-base.less file in theme

Comment: Font style showing in Email template preview but not showing into real email body content

Comment: @Camit1dk check my edit 2.

Comment: Not working @Lez

Comment: @Camit1dk did you clear static files and cache before trying? If yes, I'm sorry but I won't be able to help like this, because you have something specific in your shop. So I'd have to take a look at the files to figure out what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

Apply font location with full url in your email template

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
  }

  ...

  body {
    font-family: "Lato", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
  }
</style>
```